# How to Add Check Constraint between Tables (or change DDL)?

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

Given the following PostgreSQL table definitions:

```
postgres=# create table if not exists messages(
postgres(#     id serial primary key, 
postgres(#     max_length smallint not null check (max_length > 0),
postgres(#     default_text text check (length(default_text) <= max_length),
postgres(#     created_on timestamp with time zone not null
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# 
postgres=# create table if not exists customized_messages(
postgres(#     message_id serial references messages(id) not null,
postgres(#     message text not null, 
postgres(#     created_on timestamp with time zone not null
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE
```

how can I enforce `length(customized_messages.text)` is `<=` `messages.max_length` per the foreign key constraint?

Note that, as-is, I can do the following:

```
postgres=# insert into messages (id, max_length, default_text, created_on) values (1, 5, null, current_timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into customized_messages (message_id, message, created_on)  values (1, 'longer than 5', current_timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from messages;
 id | max_length | default_text |          created_on           
----+------------+--------------+-------------------------------
  1 |          5 |              | 2019-01-18 14:12:59.692075-05
(1 row)
postgres=# select * from customized_messages;
 message_id |    message    |          created_on           
------------+---------------+-------------------------------
          1 | longer than 5 | 2019-01-18 14:13:38.226987-05
(1 row)
```

So, I would like to not allow, e.g. check constraint or something else, the `longer than 5` to be inserted since its length is `> 5`.

Comment: Check constraint cannot reference another table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107470/3270427

Comment: Would table inheritance be a good idea, i.e. allow me to enforce this constraint?

Comment: imho your best option is a trigger or a function.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to duplicate the `max_length` column and enforce that they have identical values in the two tables with a composite foreign key (instead of the simple one):

```
create table if not exists messages(
    id serial
        primary key, 
    max_length smallint not null
        check (max_length > 0),
    default_text text
        check (length(default_text) <= max_length),
    created_on timestamp with time zone not null,
    unique (id, max_length)
);


create table if not exists customized_messages(
    message_id int not null,
    max_length smallint not null,
    message text not null
        check (length(message_text) <= max_length), 
    created_on timestamp with time zone not null,
    foreign key (id, max_length)
        references messages (id, max_length)
);
```

---

Note (irrelevant to the question):  the `message_id` column in the 2nd table does not make sense to be `serial` and at the same time `foreign key` to the 1st table.

Comment: Do you like your proposal more than adding a trigger?

Comment: @KevinMeredith yeah, DDL >> triggers in my love list ;)

Comment: So I don't need to add the `check (max_length > 0)` in `customized_messages` since it's already done in `messages`?

Comment: Yes, the foreign key and the check constraint in messages guarantees that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept in ~1 hour unless I see another answer (just to give time to other posters). Why is `unique (id, max_length)` needed though?

Comment: For the FK, a FK has to reference a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY column combination. And feel free to wait for more. DBA.SE does not usually see the rapid fire of action of SO (but you get better answers in return ;)